# Breaking Bad - Glass Frying Pan

Tags: equipment

I saw this Glass Frying Pan on "Breaking Bad" TV Series and thought it to be really cool.

Does anyone know where I can buy a glass frying pan like the one seen on Braking Bad?

Please advise!   Thanks!!

Comment: Even if you can find out, glass would be a very poor choice.   I recommend you don't go this route.

Answer (score 2):

Corning Visions, like the one below found easily with google. (So I don't paste the link, as it could be unavailable over time.)

[image: picture of Corning Visions skillet]

I had a set. It was terrible, as it was a poor conductor of heat. You ended up with hot spots, burnt food, and difficult to clean.

Answer (score 0):

Pyrex/Corning and Anchor Hocking both make lines of glass cookware. It was likely from one of these.